# how to acces object attached to element globaly in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

The code:

At the top there are a few  global settings.
On is inputElementRef which is a reference tot the input element which i am using

In the onload function obj is attached to the element using a function setPropertys.

In setPropertys i make an object cause i want to use those variables everywhere in the script
At the bottom of this function it initiates addEvent sending in the input element.

In addEvents it declared an onkeyup event with a callback giveOptions()

In giveOptions i detect the var element which is the input field on which the object is attached.

Question:
Now why is it that i have acces tot he object in the function giveOptions and why dont I have acces outside that function like at the bottom of the code.

I tried to acces those vars in the object which did not succeed.

It apears that i only have acces to the object in function giveOptions() not outside or in any other functions.

Why is that, and how can i change the code so i have acces everywhere tot he object true the input element?

/* js controller */

```
// Declare globale variables
var currentSelectedOption
var currentValue;
var arrOptions;
var inputElementRef = document.getElementById('invoer');
var outputElementRef = document.getElementById('uitvoer');



// initiate application
window.onload = function(){
// Create span (hidden) for sugest values later in script)
var spanOutput = document.createElement('span');
spanOutput.id="spanOutput";
spanOutput.style.visibility="hidden";
document.body.appendChild(spanOutput);  

// attack object to element
document.getElementById('invoer').obj = setPropertys(document.getElementById('invoer'), outputElementRef, 'responder.php', 'Geen resultaten', 1000 );   
}

// create object and add eventhandlers to element
function setPropertys(inputElement, outputElement, file, noResultMessage, timeout ){
var props={
inputElement : inputElement,
outputElement : outputElement,
file : file,
noResultMessage : noResultMessage,
timeout : timeout
};
addEvents(inputElement);
return props;
}

// attack events to elements
var isOpera = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("opera") !=-1);       // detect is user agent is opera
function addEvents(inputElement){
this.onkeyup = giveOptions;                     // all browsers use onkeyup event
if(isOpera) { this.onkeypress = giveOptions; }  // if useragent is Opera use onkeypress event   
}

function giveOptions(e){

if(window.event){                   // All browsers except firefox: window.event is available
    element = event.srcElement; 
    key = event.keyCode;
}
else{                               // if firefox use e.target and e.which
    element = e.target;
    key = e.which;
}


if(key == 13){                      // detect enter key
    console.log("enter");   
}

if(key == 38){                      // detect key up
    console.log("pijl omhoog"); 
}

if(key == 40){                      // detect key down
    console.log("key down");    
}

// Make string to send to server
var params = inputElementRef.value;

    console.log(params);
    console.log(inputElementRef.obj.file);
// Send request to server
//var newdata = net.contentLoader( 'responder.php', procesData, null, "POST", params);
}




//console.log(inputElementRef);
//console.log(inputElementRef.getAttribute('id'));
//console.log(document.getElementById('invoer').obj.inputElement);
//console.log(inputElementRef.obj.outputElement);
//console.log(inputElementRef.obj.file);
```

Comment: can you share the fiddle/html?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
console.log("input element ref: " + inputElementRef);
```

Do similar for the rest. This will output all variables as strings to your console.

**DO THIS FIRST:**

Close your `var currentSelectedOption;` <-- ' ; '

Comment: tnx, that was a mistake indeed, i got acces to the element console.log("element="+inputElementRef); But i cannot get into the obj to acces the other values which i van in the giveoptions function.

Comment: You mean this part **var params = inputElementRef.value;
    console.log(params);
    console.log(inputElementRef.obj.file);** ? It would be best if you could create a simple fiddle with your example so we could take a look at objects you create.